# Can firebase be PIPPA and HIPPA compliant?

Tags: firebase

Has anyone been able to build hippa and Pippa compliant apps using firebase. More specifically for real time and chat messaging?

some rules require data to reside in Canada.

Answer (score 0):

The Seven Fundamental Elements of an Effective [Hippa Compliance](https://www.mindbowser.com/hitech-hipaa-compliance-solutions/) Program represent the barebones requirements that HIPAA compliant apps must have in place in order to address HIPAA privacy and security standards. The Seven Elements include:

Implementing written policies, procedures and standards of conduct
Designating a compliance officer and compliance committee
Conducting effective training and education
Developing effective lines of communication
Conducting internal monitoring and auditing
Enforcing standards through well-publicized disciplinary guidelines
Responding promptly to detected offenses and undertaking corrective action